# RSpec ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken despite having sequence in FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have a model called "availabilities" in my Rails application that allows vendors to set their availability (i.e. their work hours). Thus, availabilities belong_to vendors and belong_to users, and a user has_many vendors and a vendor has_many availabilities.

I've been trying to create Rspec tests for my availability#destroy action. The specific test I refer to is:

```
#spec/controllers/availabilities_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe AvailabilitiesController, type: :controller do

  describe "availabilities#destroy action" do

    it "should allow a user who created the availability to destroy it"
      availability = FactoryBot.create(:availability) 
      sign_in availability.user
      delete :destroy, params: { id: availability.id, vendor_id: availability.vendor_id}
      availability = Availability.find_by_id(availability.id)
      expect(availability).to eq nil
   end 
  end
end
```

When I run this test however, I receive the following error:

"An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/availabilities_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: user = FactoryBot.create(:user)

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
  Validation failed: Email has already been taken"

However, I use factory bot for my factories, and I have my user factory to run as a sequence (see below):

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence :email do |n|
      "dummyEmail#{n}@gmail.com"
    end
    password "secretPassword"
    password_confirmation "secretPassword"
    confirmed_at Time.now
  end
end
```

How can the email already be taken? What could explain this error?

Comment: Could you please, show your models ?

Comment: What @Pavling said might be the case, but maybe you can do a `binding.pry` before the creation code and do an `Avalability.all` just to check. If it is the database not getting cleared out, the gem I use to clear the database out is [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) along with FactoryBot. It will give your more flexibility and eliminate the need to do this `sequence` trick. Faker generates fake data with ease.

In any way, use [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) to clean your test environment database after each test. You'll only need to set this is up:

```
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb

# start by truncating all the tables but then use the faster transaction strategy the rest of the time.
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end

# start the transaction strategy as examples are run
config.around(:each) do |example|
  DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
    example.run
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this. However, I now get this error: 

`An error occurred while loading: ./spec/controllers/availabilities_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: sign_in user `sign_in` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).`

It's good to note that up until adding the delete test, all of my 30 other tests were passing. I'm not sure where I went wrong :/